# Unit testing code dependent on DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, unit-testing

The Codewars.com description below.

> Create a function which passes in a birthday and returns how old a person is in years.

The Test Cases have already been developed for you. When the test case was created the programmer assumed there would be a shared interface between a `SystemClock` class and `StaticClock` class.

```
public class SystemClock : IClock { ... }

public class StaticClock : IClock { ... }
```

The `SystemClock` class needs to implement a `DateTime` method that returns `DateTime.Now`

The `StaticClock` method needs to implement a `DateTime` method that returns a `DateTime` value that was passed to its constructor.

The `StaticClock` implementation of `IClock` is used in our UnitTest to provide a constant time value for our unittest. Considering that time is always in motion...if we were to simply create unit test based on `DateTime.Now` then our unit test will fail over time.

With the `StaticClock` we can inject what value our `IClock.Now` method should return so our unit test will continue to pass even as time moves on.

My code below.

```
using System;

namespace AgeFromDOB
{
    public class Program
    {

        public class Kata 
        {
            private DateTime staticClock;

            public Kata(StaticClock staticClock)
            {
                this.staticClock = staticClock.Now;
            }

            public int GetAgeFromDOB(DateTime birthday)
            {
                return staticClock.Year - birthday.Year;
            }
        }

        public interface IClock
        {
            DateTime Now { get; }
        }

        public class SystemClock : IClock
        {
            public DateTime Now { get; }

            public  DateTime Method(DateTime Now)
            {
                return Now;
            }
        }

        public class StaticClock : SystemClock, IClock
        {
            public StaticClock(DateTime Now)
            {
                 Method(Now);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Kata kata;
            kata = new Kata(new StaticClock(new DateTime(2008,09,3)));
            kata.GetAgeFromDOB(new DateTime(1984,04,23));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

when I try to pass in `new Kata(new StaticClock(new DateTime(2008,09,3)));`

the object is not being passed correctly and I keep getting the wrong outcome.

I would like to know where to research or what pattern I should look at to solve this problem ?

Comment: Your title doesnt much match the post

Comment: How should I change it ?

Comment: Your `SystemClock.Method()` method always returns `DateTime.Now` and does nothing with the parameter passed to it. Perhaps start there. Your constructor for `Kata` should probably take an `IClock`, with the private field being of that type as well. You also never set the value of the `Now` property within either of your classes. You only return a value. Where is `Now=... `?  Calling `Method(Now)` returns a value which you don't use and no property is set. Attach a debugger and grab a c# book

Comment: I fixed it and saw the error but I still keep getting the wrong error

Comment: where should I research to fix this problem

Comment: Your class  StaticClock derives from SystemClock, why?  What value will SystemClock.Now return? Make sure you understand the language elements you are using. There is a "C# for absolute beginners" on Channel9, make sure you master that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Kata` is dependent on an implementation concretion when it should be dependent on an abstraction. That would allow `Kata` the flexibility at accept different implementations of the abstraction.

```
public class Kata {
    private readonly IClock clock;

    public Kata(IClock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    public int GetAgeFromDOB(DateTime birthday) {
        var now = clock.Now;    
        var age = now.Year - birthday.Year;
        if (birthday > now.AddYears(-age)) age--;
        return age;
    }
}

public interface IClock {
    DateTime Now { get; }
}
```

The two implementations of `IClock` can be kept simple based on the requirements stated in the question.

> The SystemClock class needs to implement a DateTime method that returns DateTime.Now

```
public class SystemClock : IClock {
    public DateTime Now { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
}
```

> The StaticClock method needs to implement a DateTime method that returns a DateTime value that was passed to its constructor.

```
public class StaticClock : IClock {
    public StaticClock(DateTime now) {
         this.Now = now;
    }

    public DateTime Now { get; private set; }
}
```

Which should allow you to get the desired results.

Comment: Can you please send a good article more about this and what you did

Comment: But I would love to know why I was making those mistakes

Comment: should I send this code over to code review or can send me a source to read or explain a little bit more on what you did I am looking over the code and trying to understand at the best of my ability

Comment: @GringoJaimes This covers a few topic which would be too much to include here. I would suggest reading up on SOLID principles. This answer focuses more on Dependency Inversion which is the D in the SOLID

Comment: Thank you so much I do pluralsight